# XsltListViewWebPart and custom link column

Tags: web-part, javascript, client-object-model

I have a `XsltListViewWebPart` with a custom link column used for change a value on current listitem using JavaScript.

[image: image link]

```
<a href="javascript:ApproveRejectRDA('{@ID}', true);" title="approve">

below javascript function...

function ApproveRejectRDA(id, approved) {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('RDA');
    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(id);

    if (approved == true)
       oListItem.set_item('NumStato', 16);
    else
       oListItem.set_item('NumStato', 17);

    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

When I click on link, everything works properly only when the row is selected. If not, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined

It seems that `clientContext` has no value.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I do want to say this is a brilliant use of SharePoint! I love the ability to approve and reject straight from the listview!

Comment: Can you provide some more info about the SharePoint version and why you are using XSLT at all, instead of JSLink client-side JavaScript rendering templates. Thanks!

Comment: I'm novice in SharePoint, and I don't know if this is a good solution. However, I'm working on SharePoint 2010. Any suggestion is wellcome! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it occurs since `sp.js` library that contains `SP.ClientContext` class is not yet loaded when your code runs.

Use [SP.SOD.executeFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx) to ensure that the specified `sp.js` library is loaded when the code runs.

Try to change `ApproveRejectRDA` function to enclose it in `SP.SOD.executeFunc` like this:

```
function ApproveRejectRDA(id, approved) {
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
      var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      //Your remaining code goes here...

   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new object for clientContext.
You have missed the word "new" while creating the context.

Just change the first statement as follows,

```
var clientContext = **new** SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried to create a new Object, but without success. It works only if the grid is focused (by clicking on any cell)